# Assigning a value for asp:Label based on switch statment

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, switch-statement, templatefield

I'm trying to make a cell of a GridView as a combination of an icon then a string, so far this my code

```
            <asp:GridView ID ="GV1" CssClass="myClass1" runat = "server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="StatusCustomized" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("Status").Equals("Rejected") ? "<i class=\"fa fa-check-circle\"></i> " : "<i class=\"fa fa-times-circle\"></i> ")+Eval("Status")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

but this works for only one case, so i'm thinking of using a switch statement for Eval("Status"), but i keep getting (invalid expression term 'switch'), maybe the reason is i don't actually assign the Text attribute, i just put the text in the case.

Please help me with this i will appreciate it,

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `switch` case in `RowDataBound` event.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you can use codebehind. The appropriate event is the `RowDataBound` event:

```
protected void GV1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label StatusCustomized = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("StatusCustomized");
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row; // change type of DataSource if necessary
        string status = row.Field<string>("Status");
        switch(status)
        {
            case "Rejected":
                StatusCustomized.Text = "your text";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add several `Label` controls to the `ItemTemplate` and set their `Visible` property based on the desired conditions, e.g:

```html
<asp:Label Visible='<%# Eval("Status").ToString().Equals("Rejected") %>'
           Text="<i class=\"fa fa-check-circle\"></i>" ... />
<asp:Label Visible='<%# Eval("Status").ToString().Equals("StatusX") %>'
           Text="alternate text" ... />
<asp:Label Visible='<%# Eval("Status").ToString().Equals("StatusY") %>'
           Text="yet another text" ... />
```

(Note the use of single-quote characters `Visible='<%# ... %>'`)

Or instead of using labels, you could also add other elements, such as DIVs to get clearer markup:

```
<div runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Status").ToString().Equals("Rejected") %>'
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
</div>
```

I prefer this solution over the other answer, since it doesn't put/hide parts of the markup in the code-behind.